# dt tag floating around each other in IE 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have dt tag floating around the other one on the page in IE 7, does anyone know how to fix this-

Here is the screen shot: [image: Screen of error in IE 7]

Here is a fiddle with some example code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Trcbc/), I must add that this is only a section of the faq code and not the complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi now you can define your dd display block as like this

```
dd{
display:block;
}
```

live demo http://jsfiddle.net/Trcbc/1/

---

Updated

```
#faq dt { 
display:inline-block;  //remove this
display: block;  // add this 
*display: inline;   //remove this 
*zoom: 1; //remove this
 }
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/S7mb9/3/

Comment: I can privately but as its a comapny site I would rather not put it public

Comment: here is a more complete version of the code [link]http://jsfiddle.net/S7mb9/ . The odd thing is that the bug isn't triggerd in the fiddle in IE 7

Comment: @AshleyBriscoe Now checkto this and check to my updated answer http://jsfiddle.net/S7mb9/3/  tested in all IE7+

Comment: Thank you that almost worked. I added the following hack to the dt tag and it is fine:  *display: inline-block; *zoom: 1;